# В чем смысл использования width: 100% и max-width?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, разметка

Всем привет, читаю про адаптивную верстку и встретил код для обертки сайта вида 
div.wrapper {max-width: 1200px; width: 100%}. Идея понятна: блок должен быть не шире 1200px, но может уменьшаться. Но в чем смысл ширины в 100%, если блочный элемент сам по себе тянется на всю ширину родителя?

Comment: "Доверяй, но проверяй" (ц) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это делается для адаптивной верстке. У Вас рабочая область не будет больше 1200px, но в случае если размер экрана < 1200, тогда он будет резиновым.
Но Вы правы, 100% - не самая лучшая идея. Я бы задал 94% + выравнивал по центру. Поищите источники немного поновее, так как верстка под 1200 уже отходит(за последний 2-3 года у меня не было ни одного проекта). Но это мое ИМХО

Comment: Но еще полно сайтов с `width: 640px`